# Can you help me fix my translation of 조금 걸리기는 했지만?

Tags: translation

어째 가끔은 두려워하는 눈빛이 되었던 것이 조금 걸리기는 했지만.
Is "although i feel a bit guilty because of his frightened look" right?

Because i find that 걸리다 has some meaning such as hung, caught, feel guilty, bothering, etc. I'm not sure which meaning would be fit for that sentence.

Comment: I suspect that this sentence is correct gramartically, because 되었던 것이. Where do you find this sentence ?

Comment: '걸리다' can not be translated without context. More text before and after needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) 나는 가끔은 그의 두려워하는 눈빛이 조금 걸리기는 했지만

Even though sometimes his scared eye weighed on my mind a little,

2) 그 용의자 한테서 이상한 거라도 발견 했어 ? = 걸리는 것 있어 ?

Did you find a strange point on the suspect ?

Answer (score 2):

걸리다 also means that you are concerned about sth. In your sentence, it means that you are concerned about his frightened look.